# sucrase-node não é reconhecido como comando interno

Tags: node.js

após eu fazer a instalação do sucrase e rodar o programa eu recebo o seguinte erro [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom eu consegui solucionar assim,

Criei um arquivo nodemon.json, assim:

```
{
    "execMap": {
        "js": "node -r sucrase/register"
    }
}
```

No arquivo package.json, inclui:

```
 // "scripts": {
 //   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
 ESTÁ LINHA ->   "dev": "nodemon ./src/server"
 // },
```

obs.: ./src/server é o local que está as configurações do meu serve, o seu pode estar diferente!

E pelo terminal eu chamei, assim:

$npm run dev

E solucionou este problema por aqui, espero que ajude!